# Proof Question - Fundamental Theorem of Algebra and Rational Functions

Tags: complex-analysis

I have a situation where I have a rational function $f(z)=t(z)/u(z)$, where $t,u$ are polynomials.

I would like to use the Fundamental Theorem of Algebra to show there exists a complex number such that $f(k)=k$.

My thinking is perhaps let $f(z)-k=0$ and try and use the FTA to get a result?

Thank you guys, appreciate your help.

Comment: I suggest $f(z)-z=0$ instead.

Comment: Perhaps you already spotted this, but the FTA applies to polynomial equations.  Some rewriting of the equation is needed to go from a rational to a polynomial function, and some check is needed to avoid introducing an "artifact" root.

Comment: Right thank you, so I have $t(z)-zu(z)=0$ which is a polynomial and so the FTA will be applicable which means there must exist $z\in\mathbb{C}$ such that the polynomial returns 0.

Comment: Unfortunately it's not quite that simple - if $u(z)=0$ then $t(z)-zu(z)=0$ does not quite imply $f(t)=0$. (I suspect this is the "artifact root" hardmath was referring to.)

Comment: Ok thanks, so I'm saying $t(z)/u(z)-z$ then there must exist a $k$ in C such that $t(k)=0$ by FTA and that will allow us to show $f(k)=k$?